# How do we find the smallest number of intervals covering the subset of $[0,1]$, if the intervals all have the same length of small $\epsilon$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose we have a subset of $[0,1]$ (countable or uncountable) and we cover the entire subset with the smallest number of open intervals which have the same length of a small and fixed $\epsilon$. **If the smallest number of intervals is $m$, what techniques can be used to solve $m$ in terms of $\epsilon$.** [As a note we could approximate $m$ as function of $f$, where $m\approx f(\epsilon)$]

**If there's no general techniques then what is $f$ for the following subsets of $[0,1]$?**

1. $\text{Cantor Set}$
2. $\left\{{1}/{\ln(\sqrt{n})}:n\in\left[\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\right]\right\}$
3. $\left\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$
4. $\left\{1/\sqrt{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

Comment: what happened to the early comment?

Comment: It's a good question, but I think that explicit values for $f(\epsilon)$ will be difficult to find. Not necessarily conceptually difficult; but very messy.

Comment: @TonyK You can give approximations

Comment: I think you should unaccept my answer, at least for now - having an accepted answer may dissuade others from adding more informative answers. (But thanks!)

Comment: Are your intervals of length $\epsilon$ assumed to be open or closed?

Comment: @BarryCipra They're open.

Comment: @Arbuja, thanks for the clarification. I see you've edited the question accordingly. Note that Noah Schweber's answer assumes you're using closed intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think about how to cover *finite* sets of points. Given $a_1<...<a_n$, no matter what $\epsilon$ we use we should definitely make our leftmost interval $[a_1,a_1+\epsilon]$ and our rightmost interval $[a_n-\epsilon, a_n]$. Repeating this on $$\{a_1,...,a_n\}\setminus([a_1,a_1+\epsilon]\cup[a_n-\epsilon, a_n])$$  lets us recursively calculate the relevant $m$ - for a given $\epsilon$, anyways. Some care may be needed to extract a general formula for $m$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

What about *infinite* sets of points? Well, first note that if any cover of $A$ by finitely many closed intervals also covers all the limit points of $A$. If $A$ has only finitely many limit points $p_1,...,p_k$, then - again, for a fixed $\epsilon$ - we can try to find an optimal covering of $A$ by first thinking about how to cover the $p_i$s and then considering (for such a covering) the **finitely many** points in $A$ left uncovered. This applies to your last three examples: in each case there is exactly one limit point, namely $0$. In fact in these cases $0$ is also the *leftmost* point of the closure of $A$, which means that we definitely want our optimal covering to have as its leftmost element $[0,\epsilon]$. Note that in each case this gives us an explicit finite set of remaining points! Analyzing these may still be nontrivial, but it's a much simpler-looking problem - and in some cases *is* much simpler. For example, it's not hard to calculate $m$ as a function of $\epsilon$ exactly for the set $\{{1\over 2^n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$; this is a good exercise.

Of course these are only a couple basic observations. In general even finding the asymptotics may be quite complicated. You'll find more about this if you look at [box dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension), where these values are analyzed along the way.

Comment: @NoahShweber Suppose I am using open intervals. How does this change my answer?